# Automating ftp downloads with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I want download a bunch of .txt.gz files by ftp. I've written this shell script. How do I get all the files on the sever with out specifying each file?
Some code..

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -i -n <<Here
open ftplink.com
user Username password
bin
get XXX_xxxx_mp.txt.gz
get XXX_xxxx_mp.txt.gz
close
quit
Here
```

Comment: Can't you use a wildcard like `get *_mp.txt.gz`?

Comment: @ShellFish no just tried get *_mp.txt.gz it gives me a 550 unknown file error

Comment: Use `mget` instead of `get`, if that doesn't work, try without the `-n` flag.

Comment: You could also use `ssh` rather than `ftp` and use `find -mtime` to get recent files or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget` instead:

```
wget ftp://user:pass@example.com/dir/*_mp.txt.gz
```

Comment: This is what I see when I use wget 
.listing                                [       <=>                                                           ] 137.96K  29.4KB/s   in 4.7s

==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.

.listing                                [                     <=>                                             ] 137.96K   105KB/s   in 18s

2015-04-04 09:25:54 (15.1 KB/s) - '.listing' saved [282550]

Removed '.listing'.
No matches on pattern '*_mp.txt.gz'

Comment: @BenH make sure you specify the right directory. / does not correspond to the default directory you land in with `ftp`